# /aliases: Reference to non-existent node or label "mmc0"

Tags: linux, u-boot, buildroot, device-tree

I'm trying to upstream support for u-boot and buildroot for a SoC, I'm merging some changes into master from the vendor's BSP and am having some issues with their dts.

```bsh
[machinehum@whitebox u-boot]$ make
  CFGCHK  u-boot.cfg
  OFCHK   .config
  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  ENVC    include/generated/env.txt
  ENVP    include/generated/env.in
  ENVT    include/generated/environment.h
  CC      cmd/version.o
  AR      cmd/built-in.o
  CC      env/common.o
  AR      env/built-in.o
  CC      lib/efi_loader/dtbdump.o
  LD      lib/efi_loader/dtbdump_efi.so
  OBJCOPY lib/efi_loader/dtbdump.efi
  CC      lib/efi_loader/initrddump.o
  LD      lib/efi_loader/initrddump_efi.so
  OBJCOPY lib/efi_loader/initrddump.efi
  LD      u-boot
  OBJCOPY u-boot.srec
  OBJCOPY u-boot-nodtb.bin
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-soc.dtb
arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-soc.dtb: ERROR (path_references): /aliases: Reference to non-existent node or label "mmc0"

arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-soc.dtb: ERROR (path_references): /aliases: Reference to non-existent node or label "mmc2"

ERROR: Input tree has errors, aborting (use -f to force output)
Check /home/machinehum/projects/u-boot/arch/arm/dts/.sun8iw12p1-soc.dtb.pre.tmp for errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.lib:337: arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-soc.dtb] Error 1
make[1]: *** [dts/Makefile:44: arch-dtbs] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1150: dts/dt.dtb] Error 2
```

Files added...

```
[machinehum@whitebox u-boot]$ ls -la arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1*
-rw-r--r-- 1 machinehum wheel 18983 Apr 18 14:32 arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-clk.dtsi
-rw-r--r-- 1 machinehum wheel 68163 Apr 18 16:30 arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1.dtsi
-rw-r--r-- 1 machinehum wheel   829 Apr 18 15:53 arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-fpga.dts
-rw-r--r-- 1 machinehum wheel 26226 Apr 18 14:32 arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-pinctrl.dtsi
-rw-r--r-- 1 machinehum wheel   778 Apr 18 14:32 arch/arm/dts/sun8iw12p1-soc.dts
```

sun8iw12p1-clk.dtsi: https://paste.rs/PDk

sun8iw12p1.dtsi: https://paste.rs/y9h

sun8iw12p1-fpga.dts: https://paste.rs/aQk

sun8iw12p1-pinctrl.dtsi: https://paste.rs/WZF

sun8iw12p1-soc.dts: https://paste.rs/W69

I can see "mmc0" is aliased normally in sun8iw12p1.dtsi, so I'm not sure what the problem is here. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem either. Does `.sun8iw12p1-soc.dtb.pre.tmp` contain any additional information? What if you start the `dtc` manually? And why do you alias `mmc0` at all? As far as I can see, you never use it.

Comment: At least someone else is confused :P https://pastebin.com/raw/qEWtAXXZ I have grabbed the dts from a vendor fork, so I'm not completely sure about the mmc alias. I will try dtc manually in a bit.

Comment: Another test would be to remove the alias completely …